# JS - mapping string into array of objects ¿How to change key name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 printData("customerNumber>103#customerName>Atelier graphique#contactLastName>Schmitt#contactFirstName>Carine #phone>40.32.2555#addressLine1>54, rueRoyale#addressLine2>#city>Nantes#state>#postalCode>44000#country>France#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1370#creditLimit>21000#~customerNumber>112#customerName>Signal Gift Stores#contactLastName>King#contactFirstName>Jean#phone>7025551838#addressLine1>8489 Strong St.#addressLine2>#city>LasVegas#state>NV#postalCode>83030#country>USA#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1166#creditLimit>71800#~customerNumber>114#customerName>Australian Collectors, Co.#contactLastName>Ferguson#contactFirstName>Peter#phone>03 9520 4555#addressLine1>636 St KildaRoad#addressLine2>Level3#city>Melbourne#state>Victoria#postalCode>3004#country>Australia#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1611#creditLimit>117300#~customerNumber>119#customerName>La Rochelle Gifts#contactLastName>Labrune#contactFirstName>Janine #phone>40.67.8555#addressLine1>67, rue des CinquanteOtages#addressLine2>#city>Nantes#state>#postalCode>44000#country>France#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1370#creditLimit>118200#~")
})

function printData(data){
 var customers = data
  .split('~')
  .map((i, e) => {
   return i
   .split('#')
   .map((i, el) => {
    return [i.split('>')[0],i.split('>')[1]];
   })

  });

 // $.each(customers, (i, el) => {
 //  customers[i] = el.split('#');
 //  $.each(customers[i], (name, valor) => {

 //  })
 // })

 console.log(customers);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I get data from a source in a string like this:

```
prop1>value1#prop2>value2~
prop1>value1#prop2>value2~
prop1>value1#prop2>value2
```

where:

- "~" splits rows
- "#" splits columns
- ">" splits propertie:value

this is the function i use to map it actually (where **data** is the string):

```
function printData(data){

    var customers = data
        .split('~')
        .map((i, e) => {
            return i
            .split('#')
            .map((i, el) => {
                return [i.split('>')[0],i.split('>')[1]];
            })
        });

    console.log(customers);
}
```

I almost got it, but i need a final help, this is what i get print at console:

[image]

And what i would like to get is something like

```
Array {
    customerNumber:103,
    customerName:Atelier
}
```

instead of:

```
Array{
    Array{
        0:customerNumber,
        1:103
    }
    Array{
        0:customerName,
        1:Atelier
    }
}
```

I explained it the best i can, hope it's enough!

Comment: What is helpful for these kinds of questions is if you provide the input and output and a demo to try it out. An image doesn't help.

Comment: `arr => ({[arr[0]]: arr[1]})`

Comment: @elclanrs ok! i updated it with a demo, if you look at your browser console you can see it

Comment: the old-fashioned way: `var o={}, r=i.split('>'); o[r[0]]=r[1]; return o;`

Answer (score 0):

to go from:

```
[
 ["customerNumber",103     ],
 ["customerName","Atelier" ]
]
```

to:

```
 { customerNumber:103, customerName:"Atelier" }
```

---

if that's you want to do ,
you can just remap the array:

```js
    var arr = [
      [
        ["customerNumber", 103],
        ["customerName", "Atelier"]
      ],
      [
        ["customerNumber", 105],
        ["customerName", "Atr"]
      ]
    ];

    var r = arr.map(x => {
      return {
        [x[0][0]]: x[0][1],
        [x[1][0]]: x[1][1]
      }
    });

    console.log(r)
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  printData("customerNumber>103#customerName>Atelier graphique#contactLastName>Schmitt#contactFirstName>Carine #phone>40.32.2555#addressLine1>54, rueRoyale#addressLine2>#city>Nantes#state>#postalCode>44000#country>France#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1370#creditLimit>21000#~customerNumber>112#customerName>Signal Gift Stores#contactLastName>King#contactFirstName>Jean#phone>7025551838#addressLine1>8489 Strong St.#addressLine2>#city>LasVegas#state>NV#postalCode>83030#country>USA#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1166#creditLimit>71800#~customerNumber>114#customerName>Australian Collectors, Co.#contactLastName>Ferguson#contactFirstName>Peter#phone>03 9520 4555#addressLine1>636 St KildaRoad#addressLine2>Level3#city>Melbourne#state>Victoria#postalCode>3004#country>Australia#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1611#creditLimit>117300#~customerNumber>119#customerName>La Rochelle Gifts#contactLastName>Labrune#contactFirstName>Janine #phone>40.67.8555#addressLine1>67, rue des CinquanteOtages#addressLine2>#city>Nantes#state>#postalCode>44000#country>France#salesRepEmployeeNumber>1370#creditLimit>118200#~")
})

function printData(data) {
  var customers = data
    .split('~')
    .map((i, e) => {
      return i
        .split('#')
        .map((i, el) => {
          var r = i.split('>');
          return {
            [r[0]]: r[1]
          };
        })

    });

  // $.each(customers, (i, el) => {
  //  customers[i] = el.split('#');
  //  $.each(customers[i], (name, valor) => {

  //  })
  // })

  console.log(customers);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if that is what the OP wants, surely there's a better method of accomplishing it than hard-coding a callback to the number of properties in the output object... hint: look for patterns on the two lines of the return object. some values in the columns change, some don't.

Comment: @dandavis there surely is a better way , this is just to show how to transform an array of arrays in an object;